# Powershell script no longer working, error "The assignment expression is not valid. "

Tags: powershell, syntax, hashtable, variable-assignment

I have a powershell script that has been working for a long time. But today something happended.

I now get this error:
[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idizM.png)

"The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property"

The code:

```
        $Body = [ordered]@{
            "SeriesName" = $SeriesName
            "TerminalIndex"=1
            "QuantityTypesId"=3
            "PeriodType"=4
            "Active"="true"
            "DaylightSaving"="false"
            "Tag"=$Meterpointno,
            "TimezoneId"="W. Europe Standard Time"
            "UniqueTimeZone"="false"
            "ValidPeriods"= [ordered]@{
                "GroupName"="SE.EL"
                "Source"="EBIX"
                "ValidPeriodList"= @(
                    [ordered]@{
                        "PeriodStart"=$ValidFrom
                        "PeriodEnd"=$ValidTo
                        }
                    )
                }
```

Is "TimezoneId" now some kind of systemwide variable?

Comment: You have a stray comma at the end of this line: `"Tag"=$Meterpointno,`

Comment: Yup, found it two minutes ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog) and you yourself have found the problem: a **stray `,`** (comma) at the end of **`"Tag"=$Meterpointno,`**

While your problem could therefore be considered a mere typo, the **resulting symptom is worth explaining**:

Because the  [`,` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) in PowerShell constructs arrays, and a trailing `,` at the end of a line is a *syntactically incomplete* array-construction operation, parsing continued on the next line, until the operation was complete, which included the entire following line.

That is, what PowerShell tried to assign to the `"Tag"` entry of your ordered [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) was equivalent to the following (reformatted for conceptual clarity):

```bash
$Meterpointno, "TimezoneId" = "W. Europe Standard Time"
```

To PowerShell, this is a two-element array, composed of the value of `$Meterpointno` and the string-literal `"TimezoneId"`, *to which the value of string literal `"W. Europe Standard Time"` is to be assigned*.

PowerShell *does* fundamentally support assigning to arrays - a so-called [*multi-assignment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators#assigning-multiple-variables) - but each element of the array must be a so-called [l-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue), i.e. an expression capable of *being assigned to* (storing a value).
E.g., the following is a valid multi-assignment: `$a, $b = 1..3`: it stores `1` in `$a`, and `@(2, 3)` in `$b`.

However, in your case `"TimezoneId"` is obviously *not* an l-value, i.e. it cannot be assigned to, resulting in the error message you saw (which is a verbose way of saying: not an l-value):

```
The assignment expression is not valid. 
The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept
assignments, such as a variable or a property.
```